# Using ContentProvider and CursorLoader to get Distinct values from SQLiteDatabase in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, distinct, android-cursorloader

I am trying to retrieve the distinct values from my database using my contentprovider query and CursorLoader. While the CursorLoader does not allow a distinct specification, I discovered the setDistinct method that can be added to a querybuilder for adding this specification. I am not retrieving the desired result and curious as to why. My query looks like below

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection,
                        String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // create SQLiteQueryBuilder for querying flower table
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(Flower.TABLE_NAME);
    queryBuilder.setDistinct(true);

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case OneFlower: // contact with specified id will be selected
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(
                    Flower._ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case CONTACTS: // all contacts will be selected
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    getContext().getString(R.string.invalid_query_uri) + uri);
    }

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    // configure to watch for content changes
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

while my CursorLoader looks like this

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        switch (id) {
            case LOADER_ID:
                return new CursorLoader(
                        getContext(),
                        DatabaseDescription.Flower.CONTENT_URI,
                        FROM_COLUMNS,
                        COLUMN_LOCATION + "<> ''",
                        null,
                        COLUMN_LOCATION + " ASC"
                );
            default:
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no id handled!");
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: a string. why do you ask?

Comment: @pskink not sure where you are seeing me make use of this method.

Comment: seems buildQuery is actually deprecated.

Comment: None of these really have a "distinct" parameter. buildQueryString() does but is not available by querybuilder. I believe the approach that is intended is the setDistinct(true) method that I added to the queryBuilder however it is not working which is mysterious to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help was able to solve through sync of getting a particular column and setting that as the criteria for return for the corresponding adapter.